# Apache: localhost working, server IP not (403: forbiddden)

Tags: windows, apache, virtual-machine

I'm installing apache in a Windows virtual machine and I can access it with "localhost" but when I try to access it via "http://192.168.1.34/" (which is supposed to be the machine IPv4 address) I get 403 forbidden.

My final goal is to access this apache from host machine, but so far I can't even do it from the same machine, what do I need to configure? some VirutalDirectory or what?

Thank you

PS: Windows firewall is OFF in this machine

Comment: better ask on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the server isn't bound to the external interface. See [this article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html) for more information on this topic.

Another possible option: the location is not set up for remote access:

```
<Directory "/path/to/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    Allow from xx.yy.zz.aa/sub.net.mask.here      <------ missing!!
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link but it didn´t work. I added _Listen 192.168.1.34:80_ and still _403  forbidden_. I tryed also with _<VirtualHost *:80>_ and _<VirtualHost 192.168.1.34:80>_ _Allow from all_ Still the same error, more ideas? Thanks

Comment: I have **Allow from all** and I added your config and still get the error. As as first step my goal is to access apache from the same server, but typing IP instead of localhost. This is log message: _[client 192.168.1.34] client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/Public/Www/_

Comment: you should stick to serverfault.com or post the server configuration in your question, otherwise i can't determine what happens

Comment: I'll go there (I didn't know that forum), anyway I'll post my config in next response... Thank you

Comment: Ok, solved, just adding **Listen 192.168.1.34:80** did the trick, I wasn't restarting the correct Apache instance, so sorry for your time! :-(

Comment: oops :-) of course without restarting the configuration will not be applied... No problem ;)